# Drawing polygons in pygame using list

Tags: python, pygame

I want to draw a lot of simple polygons. So I decided to make a tuple consisting of all polygons so I can draw them using
`for poly in POLYGONS`.

```
POLYGONS = (sc,(255,255,255),(0,50),ect.)

for poly in POLYGONS:
    pygame.draw.polygon(poly)
```

But when I actually do that, function takes this tuples as tge first argument. Is there any way to to this efficien(without i[0],i[1] and so on)?
I'm a beginner programmer, so that question may sound as obvious as hell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to make a list of tuples:

```py
POLYGONS = [
    ((255, 0, 0), [(100, 50), (50, 150), [150, 150]], True),
    ((0, 0, 255), [(100, 150), (50, 50), [150, 50]], True)
]
```

and you have to unzip the tuple with the [asterisk (*) operator](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#tut-unpacking-arguments):

```py
for poly in POLYGONS:
    pygame.draw.polygon(window, *poly)
```

---

Minimal example:

[image]

```py
import pygame

pygame.init()
window = pygame.display.set_mode((200, 200))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

POLYGONS = [
    ((255, 0, 0), [(100, 50), (50, 150), [150, 150]], True),
    ((0, 0, 255), [(100, 150), (50, 50), [150, 50]], True)
]

run = True
while run:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False 

    window_center = window.get_rect().center

    window.fill(0)
    for poly in POLYGONS:
        pygame.draw.polygon(window, *poly)
    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(60)

pygame.quit()
exit()
```